# Disk space full not changing after mount folder on other disk

Tags: mount, disk-usage, fstab

I have a Virtual Machine setup on azure.

I see basic disk was getting full so I attached disk to it and mounted `/home/user/mydata` folder to the new disk.

I forgot to add configuration in `fstab`.

My VM got restarted recently and after restart, I did manual `mount` but disk is not freeing after `mount` command.

```
/dev/sda1        29G   28G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.4G  8.0K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           697M  396K  697M   1% /run
none            5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       281G   63M  267G   1% /mnt
/dev/sdc1      1007G  118G  838G  13% /home/user/mydata
```

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here. What do you expect to happen after you manually mount the disk ? Also, manual mounting and mounting via fstab, has no difference other than timing, as far as the system operation goes. You need to explain better what you expect to see after mounting your new volume.

Comment: After manual mount /dev/sdc1 shows 118G data but that space is not getting freed from /dev/sda1

Comment: aaah... you are overlaying the new filesystem on the old data. When you unmount this, your old data will still be on the original disk. you need to manually delete that data, if you want the space to be freed. New filesystem, when mounted, will not suck the data from the old location. It will just sit on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mounting a disk over /home/user/mydata does NOT remove anything from the existing /home/user/mydata. It just 'covers up' the directory with the other disk.

If you want to reclaim the disk space from /home/user/mydata, you need to manually delete/move those files to the new disk before mounting.

Comment: Obviously. modded you up.